# Driver (Gd) could not be instantiated on Intervention Image, Laravel 5.4, PHP7.1

Tags: php, laravel, intervention

I got trouble with my Intervention Image, its always show "Driver (Gd) could not be instantiated."

There's installed Gd Library for PHP7.1
Tested with my simple image generator using php gd native, and image show in browser and no problem with GD

I was install PHP 7.1, Gd from homebrew
I'm using intervention/image version 2.4, Laravel 5.4

So whats wrong with my GD libray or intervention? 
Any clue for me?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything works fine when i downgrade to intervention 2.3.*

Any clue?

Answer (score 2):

I met the same issue when I try to put my code on my host,and found that 'GD' doesn't work but 'gd' works well to me